# How to remove author filter from SonarQube issue overview

Tags: sonarqube

I was asked by my workers council to remove the author and assignee filter from the SonarQube issues page. I'm using SonarQube version 6.7.7 (build 38951).

Currently I don't see any option to configure this. Is there any option to remove the filter? I know that I can disable to analysis of of the SCM commits at all, but I want to keep the my issues feature and the notification on new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is impossible by using only SonarQube (check the proposal about the nginx proxy configuration) and won't be implemented. Read more details here: [SONAR-11028 Turning off developer nominative information/metrics](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-11028).

Answer (score 0):

Finally we are now using a workaround that filters certain requests to the SonarQube API with an nginx reverse proxy.

Here is a configuration example:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass         http://sonarqube:9000;
        }
        location /api/issues/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_pass         http://sonarqube:9000;
            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter_types application/json;
            sub_filter 'authors' 'XXXXXXXXXX';
            sub_filter 'assignees' 'XXXXXXXXXX';
        }
    }
}
```